# Django server details

Tags: django, python-2.7, web, server, wsgi

I have been working with django since 2 years, still confuse with some of the server related concepts of django as follows:-

1. What `web server` does `django` use when I run `python manage.py runserver`?
2. What is `wsgi`(I know it is `web server gateway interface`(sets of rules can say protocols) act as an middle-ware for the communication of web server and web application) then `wsgi` is the server django runs on?

Comment: Please explain the down votes, because I research lot before putting this question.

Comment: You might find it useful to read this series of posts. https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/

Answer (score 2):

From [this code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L10) - Django has built in WSGI Server which is used to serve the app when we use `runserver`. The server code can be [found here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/servers/basehttp.py). However this is not recommended to be used in production.

`WSGI` is a protocol, a standard. You can build your own web server which complies to this standard (like Django's built in server). Or you can use one of the open source, production ready, mature and battle proven wsgi servers. Personally I like `uwsgi`.